# How to replace a ForEach when there's only on item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui, foreach

I wonder if it's possible to replace the `ForEach` below as I only have one "product" into the `products` array?

```
if !storeManager.products.isEmpty {
    ForEach(storeManager.products) { product in
        Button(action: {
            // Something here
        }, label: {
            Text("Purchase")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just skip the `ForEach` ... if you have to access properties of `product` use `storeManager.products.first` ... or if you always have only one product, don't use an array, but just `storeManager.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `if` to check the count and then show different views depending on the result

```
let products = ["MacBook Pro"]
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if products.count == 1 {
            button(product: products[0])
        } else {
            ForEach(products, id: \.self) { product in
                button(product: product)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

func button(product: String) -> some View {
    Button(action: {
        // Something here
    }, label: {
        Text("Purchase \(product)")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't need the `if statement + count` but the other part will be very useful. I also wonder, is it best to use `products[0]` or `products.first!`?

Comment: I prefer `products[0]` here but it's a matter of taste